# What is the best way to align content DIV vertically and horizontally on image in responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

What is the best way to align content DIV vertically and horizontally on image  in responsive.I can give position absolute and align `top:some%`,and `left:some%` but it wont align middle of the image container in some screens, and i can give `margin-top:-%`,`margin-left:some%` this one also won't align properly for some times means in different screens.Is there any other way to do it.The content div should be exactly placed middle(horizontally and vertically in all screens) on the image. what is the best way to do it?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <img src="img/someimage.png" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="content_div">
       image content paragraph 1
       image content paragraph 1
       image content paragraph 1
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content div must be placed at the middle of image.

```
  <div class="container">
    <img goes here>
    <div text goes here>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
 .contianer
 {
   position: relative;
 }

 .container img, .container .txt
 {
    position: absolute;
 }

 .container img
 {
   //Width and height
  }

 .container .txt
 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: height of image div; // It ll pace in the middle of image
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/raa74987/) It ll help you.

Another way is

```
  set table layout for div and table-cell for content which will support vertical-align:middle`
```

**EDIT:**

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/WXLsY/348/) -- It ll help You.

Thanks to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105814]/nice-ass)

Comment: i cant fix width and height of  `.container `,so i can't give line-height in `px`

Comment: Then go for table layout.

Comment: thanks for reply.my problem is i cant fix `height` but i can make `width:100%`.height should be auto and width should be 100%.then only responsive will be good.

Comment: [DEMO4](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/WXLsY/352/) Oh Come on Man. Change it in the fiddle and check. Its just fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71474/discussion-between-dileep-and-gops-ab).